# Getting controller variables in a loader view method?

Tags: php, class, object, object-oriented-analysis

I'm building a script that got a static class used to load few things including files and views.

```
class load
{
    public static function view($file_path, $area)
    {
        debug::log('getting view <b>' . $area . $file_path . '</b>.');
        ob_start();
        self::file($file_path, 'areas/' . $area . '/views');
        debug::log('flushing view <b>' . $area . $file_path . '</b>.');
        eturn ob_get_clean();
    }

    public static function file($file, $folder)
    {
        if(is_file($file_path = ROOT . '/' . $folder . '/' . $file)) 
        {
            if(require_once $file_path)
            {
                debug::log('file <b>' . $file_path . '</b> included.');
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
            debug::kill('requested file <b>' . $file_path . '</b> does not exist.');
    }   
}
```

In the controller Im calling the view method to get a view:

```
$html = load::view('public', 'path/to/view/file.php');
```

Obviously, Im not able to access the variables from the controller at the view file using this practice, so I did a small modification on the view class to capture the vars:

```
public static function view($file_path, $area, $vars = array())
```

And added the following lines of codes to get the keys into vars:

```
while(list($n_list_var,$v_list_var)=each($vars))
        $$n_list_var = $v_list_var;
```

But again I can't access the vars since Im using a method to load a file.

I have a method to load the files because I wanna test and log each file include attempt and not repeat the code every time I need include a file. And I have the loader view inside the loader class so I have all the methods of this kind together. Should I give up on using a class to load files? Should I use the loader view method on a extendable class from my controller?

Instead of going ahead and modify my entire script I would like to hear some opinions ... what would be the best practice to go? Or is there a way to solve my problem? Maybe using __set and __get magic methods?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass a `$vars` argument to `load::file()` and `extract( $vars )` (possibly moving the vars you use inside `file()` into class variables to prevent them from being overwritten)?

I'm suggesting using `extract()` instead of:

```
while(list($n_list_var,$v_list_var)=each($vars))
    $$n_list_var = $v_list_var;
```

By the way, it would be a good idea to name your class `Load`.

Comment: the load::file method gonna be used to include files only and can be used to load a file containing a class as well so extracting vars would be unnecessary. So it gonna be a bad practice on my understand. That is why Im looking for some alternatives. (Thanks, I totally forgot about extract() function). And why it would be a good idea to name Load?

Comment: Ok, when you want to load a file without making any variables available to it, can't you just omit the `$vars` array?  Many people, myself included, consider capitalizing class names a good convention.

Comment: yes I can do that. I just think its a bad practice. Maybe the entire thing Im doing is not a good practice so Im trying to get more inputs on alternatives to this issue. I will do that if nothing else comes to me. Thanks,

Comment: "I just think its a bad practice." -- how so? Please elaborate.

Comment: I mean, the hole thing about using a method to include a file is sounding a bad practice. I can use it to include classes but including files containing $vars they won't be accessible on the external script calling the method, so I can't use it for this purpose. And passing variables into this method, don't seems the best option as well cause this method gonna be used to load classes where vars won't be needed to be passed. The code don't seems clean to me.

Comment: But than, I just wanna a way to don't be repetitive checking if a file exist, than include and if don't exists, throw an error.